# what's a framework used to build a wpf project?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, frameworks

i had an interview yesterday. i'm new with the wpf technology and they asked me what's the framework i used to build my project? (it's not .Net framework)
it's smth like best practices.
have you an idea about this?

Comment: Dear Amine antri WPF is .Net related framework. No other framework available for that. WPF available only on .Net framework. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several MVVM frameworks to build WPF applications like the following:

- [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/)
- [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx)
- [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

I believe that for other than trivial applications you should use a MVVM framework.

Comment: @Downvoter. Why is this answer downvoted?. This is the first time I see an acepted answer with downvotes.